# OracleGoldenGate: Update transaction does not update some columns (keeps it null) in replica. While in source it has updated value

Tags: sql, database, oracle, replication, oracle-golden-gate

We are using Oracle Golden Gate 19C (integrated mode, microservice)  to replicate the online transaction from source to target.
For most of the transaction it does replicate exactly as in the source. But for one online operation which has one insert and 2 updates, what we observe that few columns are not updated.
Then I started checking the first thing, the trail file of Extract process, using logdump. It reveals that the trail files "after image" does not have other columns it has only few columns.
So if we have valid insert and update and data is visible correctly in the source data, then why does the trail files does not have these columns?
Example of the situation:

```
Source: DB_Src (database version is 19C)
Table: TRAN_TABLE (COMPRESSED)
Columns: Date, Userid, EffectiveDate
ALTER DATABASE ADD SUPPLEMENTAL LOG DATA (ALL) COLUMNS;
ALTER DATABASE FORCE LOGGING
```

Extract Process Parameter:

```
extract ...
useridalias ...
exttrail ...
userid ...
setenv (ORACLE_HOME =...)
trace ..
DISCARDFILE ...
GETUPDATEBEFORES
LOGALLSUPCOLS
UPDATERECORDFORMAT FULL
TABLE MYSCHEMA.*;
```

After Insert at source:

```
Table: TRAN_TABLE
Columns: Date, Userid, EffectiveDate
Values: 2021-10-01 10:00:01, ABC,  null
```

After Update at source:

```
Table: TRAN_TABLE
Columns: Date, Userid, EffectiveDate
Values: 2021-10-01 10:00:02, ABC,  2021-11-01
```

But what we see in target (after replica) is :

```
Table: TRAN_TABLE
Columns: Date, Userid, EffectiveDate
Values: 2021-10-01 10:00:02, ABC,  null
```

So EffectiveDate column is not updated. When I check the trail file it shows data of update afterimage for only change in 1 column.

```
Columns: Date, Userid, EffectiveDate
Values: 2021-10-01 10:00:02, .,  .
```

So the issue is that trail file is not capturing all the columns!
What could be the reason?
(A) All columns are set at database level
(B) GETUPDATEBEFORES are also set in the parameter.

Can someone help please?

Comment: Hi! Can you please provide table creation and exact sequence of insert/update commands you're issuing?

Comment: @Roman I had noticed that when we have two unique index on the same table (which is involved in transaction) then it was giving the issue. Then searching the internet found explanation, and changing the index name it got solved. This seems some known phenomena, if two unique index then OGG picks one of the index in alphabetical order. One relevant url: [link](https://www.bersler.com/blog/oracle-goldengate-using-unique-index-instead-of-primary-key/).

Answer (score 2):

If the same table we have two unique index then OGG uses one of the index picking first in alphabetical order. Say we have two uniue index as uidxA(col1,col2) and uidxB(col1,col3), and the transaction has used the columns of uidxB, but OGG will use uidxA (alphabetical order) and will refer the columns of uidxA. Now transaction has not used the col2, so this is null in trail file. Hence, OGG fails.

I changed the index name, from uidxB to uidx0B so that this will be used by OGG then it worked.

Reference user about two unique index :
https://www.bersler.com/blog/oracle-goldengate-using-unique-index-instead-of-primary-key/

Posting my reply as it can help others.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! In your case it would be better to convert the most convenient index to primary key. OGG will take it as a key.